# I've got lots of reputation- why does it keep welcoming me back and reminding me to vote?

Tags: feature-request

It's been 10 minutes since I last visited the site, a day or two since I visited via -this- browser.

I've been on here for years- why does it keep reminding me to vote on the question I landed on and wasting prime vertical realestate?

How about it stop doing newb reminders for people who aren't newbs?

Comment: I believe that that goes away with the [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilage.

Comment: Great Caesar's Ghost, Batman.  My first post was Oct 15 '10. That means, if you're correct, it might stop reminding me to upvote good posts by 2023 or so... That's nuts.

Comment: Or you could stop getting it before the end of the day if you answer a bountied question.

Comment: @DragandDrop quoted or unquoted, "newb" today is pretty much as negatively loaded as "nerd" was 15 years ago. In other words: speak for yourself :)

Comment: on-topic: I remember seeing that message when I was still under 1k, but I don't remember getting it all the time. I did get it when I was in the habit of upvoting answers but not the question, and it went away when I did start to upvote questions. At least... I think? Its been years...

Comment: @Gimby, We (except Jon) always are somebody else's "newbs". Is it better this way? I always have hard time finding the right idiom to express myself, sorry if it was offending

Comment: @Gimby idk about then, but I have been noticing this freaking reminder quite a bit these last few months, and I vote about equally on questions and answers. I think they should drop the bar from 1000 to 50, or maybe look directly at how many times we've actually voted.